# Arduino serial communication broken. Possible due to short circuit

Tags: serial

So I have a project I'm working on where I have about 6 arduino boards communicating with one another through cables. I've been testing them using a regulated DC PSU and at some point I caused a short and since then I can't upload any sketches onto the arduino. On some of them, the TX pin will light up while trying but RX won't and the IDE tends to freeze after around 90% of the upload process is complete.

Does anyone know how badly I screwed up? How do I avoid this next time? Is there an easy fix?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you give more details about the short circuit? Where did the current go?

Comment: Can you say us which Arduino board you have? Maybe you can switch the micro itself or maybe not

Comment: Try disconnecting the arduinos from each other, use a different power supply,plug pack or power via usb from pc and try programming and running them one by one. Try the simplest program possible and go from there(led flash of onboard led then change pins and use a led with resistor to check if you have blown any io pins).Which boards as if its older ones you may have just damaged the usb to serial chip. Or if a dip not smd board you maybe able to just replace the atmel chip. More details, circuit diagram and maybe a link to a picture would help us help you.